# What is the $hf_mig$ directory for in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003

What is the `$hf_mig$` directory for in Windows Server 2003, and can I delete it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its name means "hotfix migration".  It's for tracking versioning information about hotfixes to keep from accidentally breaking or downgrading your system.  No, you definitely should not delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good explanation of the topic: [What is the “$hf_mig$” Folder for And Can I Delete It?](http://blog.ryantadams.com/2008/02/21/what-is-hf_mig-and-can-i-delete-it/)